# gmaps4rails dynamic load question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Trying to modify the screencast to be unobtrusive. Have an action (updatemap) that completes the following query:

```
 @markers = Location.active.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

Then in updatemap.js.erb:

```
Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers(?);
```

With it empty the markers clear so I know that works but can't figure the proper syntax to go between the parenthesis to display the new markers.

@markers, is stored in JSON format but how do get them to be entered, tried `<%= @markers %`> but that failed.

Comment: What if you try `<%=raw @markers %>` ?

Comment: Works perfectly... Great app...

Comment: Just posted a real answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the json as safe or render it raw:

```
Gmaps4Rails(<%=raw @markers %>);
```